# VBA to copy selected value of dropdown in Word Doc into specific Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, dropdownbox

I am trying to return the text from a dropdown box that is selected on a Word form.

The word doc is a survey that contains a form with several dropdown boxes.  I want to copy the value that the survey respondent selected from each dropdown into specific cells in Excel.

I have tried things such as:

```
Activedocument.DropDowns("DropDown1").Value;
Activedocument.DropDowns("DropDown1").Text; 
Activedocument.DropDowns("DropDown1").SelectedValue; 
Activedocument.Shapes("DropDown1").Value etc etc.
```

Current applicable parts of my code:

```
Dim dd14 As FormFields
With ActiveDocument
Set dd14 = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dropdown14").DropDown.Value
Cells(iRow + 1, "H") = dd14
End With
```

Comment: Is this an activex control, or form control? Combobox or dropdown list?

Answer (score 1):

To reference the value for a legacy form dropdown field to get the value (which is the index, not the text of the selected item) the code is:

```
  activedocument.FormFields("dropdown1").DropDown.value
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using that, I get a Type Mismatch Error on ".Value". I just pasted applicable parts of my code above.

Comment: youre getting a type mismatch because youre setting a formfield object equal to a value.  If you dim dd14 as long i believe this should work

Comment: Got it to work when I changed the dim to Integer and removed "set"  Thank you for your help.